# running only one twisted looping call

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I am using twisted looping call in my twisted server to call a once after a particular time interval. My code is following:

```
class Echo(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        self.setRawMode()
        startClock(self)
        print 'Connected Client', self._peer

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
        print 'Lost connection from', self._peer

    def rawDataReceived(self, data):
        inputArray = ["%02X"%ord(inp) for inp in data]
        if(CheckPacket(inputArray)):
            PacketParser(inputArray, self)
        else:
            print "Fail"
            d = self.transport.getHost ()
            print d.type

def startClock(self):
    l = task.LoopingCall(partial(sendTimeRequest,self))
    l.start(660.0)

def main():
    port = 8000
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    factory.clients = []
    try:
        reactor.listenTCP(port,factory)
    except Exception, ex:
        print "Port %d is busy: %s" % (port, ex)
    reactor.run()
```

Thus my problem is that every time new client connects to server a new looping call will start. How can I make sure that their is only one looping call is running even if their are more then one client connected to server? Currently it is happening in following way, when first client connects to server a twisted looping call starts, calling let's say function a() after every 10 seconds. Then after 2 seconds another client connect to server then another looping call starts calling function a() after every 10 second but the finally it becomes like this

> elapsed time| function called
>
> 10 sec| a()
>
> 12 sec| a()
>
> 20 sec| a()
>
> 22 sec| a()

but I want function a() to called only after each 10 seconds irrespective of no. of clients connecting to server.

Comment: `to call a once after a particular time interval`?

Comment: their should be only one looping call running while now every time new client connects to server a new looping call starts.

Comment: There's an edit button at the bottom of the questiom.  Please fix the question. :)  In case it isn't clear, the grammar of the question seems broken to me.  I can't understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: Not the part that I quoted and that I don't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one `Protocol` instance per connection.  Each instance has its `connectionMade` method called when the connection is made.

This method:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    self.setRawMode()
    startClock(self)
```

is called once per connection, therefore `startClock` is called once per connection.

Contrasted with this is your `main` function.  It is called only once.  If you put a `startClock` call in `main` and take it out of `connectionMade` then `startClock` will only be called once.  It will be called at program startup time before any connections have been made and never again.

Notice that the code already maintains a list of `Protocol` instances on the factory instance.  This means that given a reference to the factory you can reach all of the `Protocol` instances.  This means that if you pass the factory as an argument to the function you're looping...

Comment: how can I pass self object if I move startclock to main?

Comment: You said you wanted one loop, you didn't say what you wanted the loop to do.

Comment: sorry, I guess I had not clearly stated my question.